# ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [dbkif_find_next_record_1]

Tags: oracle, sqlps

I m trying to start my database by sqlPlus : but I get this error :

```
 SQL> startup
 Instance ORACLE lancÚe.
 Total System Global Area 1686925312 bytes
 Fixed Size                  2176368 bytes
 Variable Size            1207962256 bytes
 Database Buffers          469762048 bytes
 Redo Buffers                7024640 bytes
 Base de donnÚes montÚe.
 ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [dbkif_find_next_record_1], [], 
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

any suggestion please ?

Comment: Check Oracle's support site, or raise a service request with them? ORA-00600 is an internal error code and that is their standard advice. If you run `oerr ora 600` the action says: Visit My Oracle Support to access the ORA-00600 Lookup tool (reference Note 600.1) for more information regarding the specific ORA-00600 error encountered.

Comment: As @AlexPoole suggested - check Oracle's support site for known bugs, and raise a SR if it's  a new one.